# Bash script to copy all files in current directory modified recently into a newly created folder elsewhere

Tags: bash, shell, command, alias

Few more specifics:

- I want to first create a new directory on the desktop. The name of the directory will be the current date and time.
- I want to copy all files (recursively) in the current working directory that have been modified in the last 20 minutes into that new folder.
- Lastly, I'm planning on aliasing this to make it look like it isn't a known command so I echo a fake "command not found"

Here is what I came up with: (All 1 line, split for readability)

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/$(date +%F-%T) 
&& find . -mmin -20 -exec cp -r {} ~/Desktop/$(date +%F-%T) \; 
&& echo "bash: cr: command not found"
```

I didn't like how I was specifying the destination directory for the copy by having to get the date and time again.

Here is my second attempt with changes in bold:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/$(date +%F-%T) 
&& find . -mmin -20 -exec cp -r {} **$(find ~/Desktop/ -type f -cmin -1)** \; 
&& echo "bash: cr: command not found"
```

This time, I just grab whatever folder is on the desktop that was created less than a minute ago. This still seems like a weak solution to me considering that if I run the command 2 times within 60 seconds, it will fail, since the "find" (in bold) will return 2 folders which is invalid for the cp command...

Now the challenge I pose is how do I make this work if my current directory is the desktop? I don't want to copy the newly created folder into itself! Also, how can I avoid getting any additional output from the cp? Sometimes I get warnings/errors telling me I am trying to copy a file to the same location where it already is!

Any other methods of accomplishing this are more than welcome, but I'm curious how mine can be modified to make it work peoperly

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the old programming adage of making variables or functions for things you use more than once.

```
folder="$(date +%F-%T)" \
&& mkdir "$HOME/Desktop/$folder" \
&& find -type d -name "$folder" -prune -o -type f -mmin -20 -exec cp {} "$HOME/Desktop/$folder" + \
&& echo "bash: cr: command not found"
```

Also note,

- `find` is already recursive, so don't use `cp -r`
- Modification time has somewhat different meanings for directories and files, and it sounds like you only want to copy files, so limit it to `-type f`
- Also, you can use `+` instead of `;` for commands that can take more than one file as arguments. (it will run `cp file1 file2 file3 ... "$folder"` rather than seperate `cp` commands, and ultimately run as few `cp` commands as possible, splitting them up on `ARG_MAX`, and optimizing performance a bit)
- To omit the directory, I used `-type d -name "$folder" -prune`, which will stop `find` from descending directories named `"$folder"`. This may cause your command to miss some other directories if they happen to contain the exact same name, but otherwise it should work as expected. (If you always launch it from the same directory, this could be improved to match the exact path, or you could do a more complicated `-exec` check, but I think this should work in most cases)